Children's TV Show featuring aliens, a treehouse and tumbleweed
For the past few months/years, my wife has been trying to remember a VHS their mother bought them.  Unfortunately, they have very little to go on; here is what we know:

It was animated,
It featured aliens with varying antennas,
It was set in a desert-esque environment, but there were tree-houses,
The trees were drawn as swirls, with blobs of colour,
There was a tumbleweed,
There was an episode in which colour was lost
It would have been in the 90's (although the show may have been released earlier)

We have searched high and low, the ruled out most of the lists that appear on Google.
Can anyone place it, or have any ideas of what it may have been?

Animated or live-action?

I've updated the question to include that it was animated.  Thanks!

Try looking on here. There's a lot of archived data to browse.
http://cartoonresearch.com/
